# Selenium in virtual machine is slower than desktop

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, firefox, selenium

I've set up a kvm virtual machine, CentOS 6 on both guest and host. I'm using selenium on the guest in order to test a web site. However, it loads significantly slower than trying to hit the web site on my desktop. It is also pretty inconsistent. I'm seeing anywhere from 4-15 second load times. I'm guessing most of that time is page rendering. The load on both the host and the guest is nearly zero. If I try and access the guest via vnc, the gui appears to be laggy in general. Browser being tested is firefox.

My guess is that there is some issue with the video/the rendering of the web site. kvm is using the "cirrus" video driver, and is reporting 9m of ram allocated. CentOS guest is also using gnome, which I am assuming tries to use hardware acceleration out of the box.

My question: how can I get better Selenium benchmarks from my test server?

Thanks!

Comment: Um, switch it to SPICE video? I can't imagine why it would ever be set to cirrus.

Comment: It looks like my options for video are "cirrus", "vga", "vmvga", and "xen". I haven't heard of SPICE video before. Is there any way to tell if the video driver is the bottleneck?